# How to implement operator-> for iterator type?

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading

Is there a way to implement operator->, not only operator*. To have following code working:

```
Iterator<value> it = ...
i = (*it).get();
i = it->get(); // also works
```

Let we say that value type has method get.
When Iterator is implemnted as below:

```
template<T> class Iterator {
    T operator*() { return ... }
    T operator->()  { return ... }
 }
```

Here ... is an implementation of getting right T object.

Somehow it won't work when I implement it in this way. I think I misunderstand something.

Comment: You can also find an example here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: In particular, read "Operators for Pointer-like Types" of ["Common operators to overload"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/90527) from the question Mike links to, paying close attention to the signature of `operator->`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`operator->` should return a pointer:

```
T * operator->();
T const * operator->() const;
```

`operator*` should return a reference if you want to use it for modification:

```
T & operator*();
T operator*() const; // OR T const & operator*() const;
```

Answer (score 7):

As odd as this may seem, you want to return a pointer to T, thusly:

```
T * operator->() { return &the_value; }
```

Or a pointer to const.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify what "it won't work" means - does it fail to compile, or does something else than expected? I will assume it compiles, because from your snippet I can't see why it shouldn't.

What you are doing is returning *by value*. So you return a new instance of the pointed-to object. You instead should return a pointer in `operator->` and reference in `operator*`

Comment: It won't compile, but I don't remember the right error message.